# A good dual or even three channel router

Tags: wifi, router, ethernet, internet-of-things

I'm looking for a dual- or multi-channel router. Requirements:

- 2/3 or more channels
- Supports IP/TV as well as the standard functionality
- Reliable brand (think Asus, D-Link)
- Not more than €300.

Answer (score 3):

These are the two routers which match your requirements and these were released recently. These are tri-band routers which do not reduce speed even when multiple devices are connected to the same network **i.e** A tri-band router is literally hosting two separate 5 GHz networks, and it automatically sorts devices into different networks. This offers more speed to share among your devices even if you are using heavy data on one network (eg;- 4k).

***Asus RT-AC3200 Tri-Band Router - 200€***

It has six adjustable antennas featuring three bands 2.4Ghz(1) and 5Ghz(2)
It has solid performance in the 5Ghz band and has a bunch of features like multiple LED indicators. It under performs when handling files through LAN(file transferring) and it is a tad expensive.

***D-Link AC3200 Ultra Wi-Fi Router (DIR-890L/R)- 200€***

Similar to the Asus it has 6 antennas with tri-band, 2.4Ghz and two 5Ghz bands. It has an awesome build and a multiple LED indicators like the Asus. It can really handle files and heavy data without breaking a sweat. Even though it has very less cons it is priced at an expensive price point.